# league/sftp Connection closed prematurely

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, sftp, phpseclib

I've got a long-living process controlled by supervisor written in php, it's a Laravel command listening on a redis channel. It pushes data from the channel to another server via SFTP using the leagure/sftp library when the data arrives. The problem that it works normally only during about 12 hours after starting the process and starts returning the following error thereafter:

> File:
>   /var/www/html/hub/vendor/phpseclib/phpseclib/phpseclib/Net/SSH2.php
>
> Line: 3416
>
> Code: 0
>
> Message: Connection closed prematurely

The process needs restarting to work normally another 12 hours.

Do you guys have any idea?

Comment: Post the log files. phpseclib limits them, by default, to 1mb. You can get them by doing `define('NET_SSH2_LOGGING', 2)` at the top and then `$ssh->getLog()` when you get that error. Maybe what you could do is write an error handler that, whenever that kind of error is "caught", the log file is generated. Then, once you have the log file, post it on pastebin.org.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is resolved by reconnecting every time before accessing the SFTP server:

```
/**
             * @var \Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemAdapter $disk
             */

            $adapter = $disk->getDriver()->getAdapter();
            $adapter->disconnect();
            $adapter->connect();
```

Comment: I came across this fix and was wondering if there is any explanation about this?

Comment: @RobertFridzema apparently the remote server closes the connection after a timeout and the client needs to reconnect

Comment: I use this fix now for a couple of weeks and seems to work for most of the time, but at random times it trows the error fputs(): send of 52 bytes failed with errno=32 Broken pipe on the line `$adapter->disconnect();`

Answer (score 0):

It's same subject here or not?

[[Perl][net::ssh2] How to keep the ssh connection while executing remote command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13457178/perlnetssh2-how-to-keep-the-ssh-connection-while-executing-remote-command)

An other solution is re-auth to the server before the 12 hours.

Comment: No, it doesnt seem the same. And the league/sftp adapter doesn't have any api to reauth. Weird why it's working a whole day and starts loosing the connection by evening.